# Indentation for floatfoot command

Tags: footnotes, indentation, chemistry

I am using a variety of footnote commands for my thesis:

`\bibnote` to add numerical footnotes to text. The note should appear both on the same page (as a footnote) and in the bibliography (as an endnote). The footnote is separated by the rest of the text through a horizontal line.

For other reports before I used `\footnotetext` to add footnotes (alphabetical) to schemes or figures.

However, since I started printing references both on the same page (as footnotes) and in the bibliography as endnotes I was forced to add a macro for a horizontal line between text and footnotes, which also adds a horizontal line between schemes and `\footnotetext`, which I do not want.

To circumvent this problem I chose to use the command `\floatfoot*` which does not add a horizontal line between my float and the footnote.

The problem is: `\floatfoot*` does not add an indentation which makes the note look quite ugly in my eyes.

Does anyone have an idea how to either add indentation to the `\floatfoot` command or circumvent the explained problem in a different manner?

Thanks in advance!

[image: An explaining picture]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, letterpaper]{scrbook}   
\usepackage[cmsy]{MnSymbol} 
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MyriadPro}

%%%Setup for the header containing a line with the chaptername and number
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
  \headrule\sethead{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle}{}{}
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}  

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{relsize}
\setchemnum{replace-style = \scriptsize}
\usepackage{longtable}      
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{listings}
%%%both needed for notes2bib
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\bibnotesetup{cite-function=\autocite} %%%superscript bibnotes

\usepackage{graphicx}%              
\usepackage[section]{placeins}      
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf} %needed for chemnum
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       
\usepackage[journal=jacs, tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}


\makeatletter
    \def\fps@figure{tbp}
\makeatother

\usepackage[url=false, doi=false, natbib=true, backend=bibtex, style=chem-acs]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
\addbibresource{latexlit.bib}%


%%%Macro for having both footnote and endnotes for citations
\makeatletter
% source of macro: http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen{}{\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
    \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{\fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
\makeatother

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Stackexchange}

For the preparation of \cmpd{latex1} it was envisioned to use \cmpd{latex2} as a precursor


\begin{scheme}[htbp]
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\replacecmpd[tag=TMP1]{latex1}
\replacecmpd[tag=TMP2]{latex2}
\replacecmpd[tag=TMP3]{latex3}
\includegraphics[scale=.638]{Images/latex1}
\caption{Stackexchange}
\label{latex1}
\floatfoot*{The floatfoot command does not product a horizontal line. But the indentation is missing.}

\footnotetext{Using the footnotetext command causes a horizontal line to appear above which is unwanted, but the desired indentation appears}

\end{scheme}

A sentence with a bibnote.\bibnote{Silly description of a reaction using the bibnote command.}

Usual literature citation in the text appears both as a footnote and endnote\autocite{Hurtley:2014ft}.

\footnote{A footnote using its own counter}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a MAXIMAL Non-working example! Too many stuff not related to the question. Please make your code minimal and reproducing the problem.

Comment: As there is no error to be reproduced I put the MWE in mainly to show my way of thought and make people able to check for incompatible packages.